# Connect to network station via SSH using Java having issues

Tags: java, ssh

I am trying to connect to Network station that has a device that has an IP and username and password.

This station has a specific command to Run *not any command for example: "ls" command will not run. It must be one of its commands*.

When i using Putty to connect to this station everything is fine. *as this PS*

[image: This is When using Putty to connect]

I am using Java code to connect to that station via SSH using com.jcraft.jsch library.
In connecting, I am checking whether the session.isConnected() return true of false but it's return true. So till now everything is fine.

But in this part:

```
InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(in));
line = reader.readLine();
```

At line = reader.readLine() it took a huge amount of time and there is no output or Exceptions or anything after that.

Does anyone have any idea?

[image: Screenshot of the code and output]

Comment: Do you have any logs or something to track or any kind of screenshot?

Comment: @Abhinav I updated the description. You will find at the end of the description the screenshot for the code and output

Comment: Well, I have posted my answer! :)

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have written both the statements one after the other like below:-

```
System.out.println("############# - " + reader.read());
String line;
line = reader.readLine();
```

Therefore, it is nowhere taking huge time in any computation or something. It is the user (you) who is supposed to give the input 2 times in the prompt. ***You can try hitting the enter key twice!***

Comment: But when i use the exact same code with another normal server and replace .setCommand("ZJHI:0") with .setCommand("ls") for example it runs normally 

And Variable "line" holds all the files and directories return from command "ls" normally and print it inside while loop

Comment: Did you get the meaning of reader.readLine() in your code? Just enter any string in your Putty prompt where the cursor is blinking & hit enter!

Comment: Yes Reader.readLine() is reading a new line from "in" which is the input stream from channelExec. 
BTW I've entered any command in the blank .. but still get nothing :(

Comment: @abdelrhmantarek Modified my answer. Please do have a look & let me know whether you got a clear picture of the current scenario or not.